# How to set variable value inside the remote server

Tags: shell, unix

Inside the remote server i have a condition statement.If that condition passes
status value should be set as success.

But here i am always getting Failure response while i print status variable

status='Success';

`status='Success';`

```
# !/bin/bash

declare -a server_PP=('XXXXX' 'YYYYYYY' );
declare -A results_map;


function process(){
serverList=$1[@];
servers=("${!serverList}");
status='Failure';
for  serverName in "${servers[@]}"
do
    ssh  $serverName  <<  EOF
          if [ -f /app/Release/abc.war ]; then
            echo "available - success"
            status='Success';
          fi
echo "***********status-inside******$status"
        exit
EOF
echo "***********status-outside******$status"
results_map+=([$serverName]=$status);
done

}


process 'server_PP'

for i in "${!results_map[@]}"
do
  echo "key :" $i
  echo "value:" ${results_map[$i]}
done
```

Status variable should set as success when that condition get satisfied.

Comment: You are running a remote shell script on the server using ssh. The `status` variable there is completely independent of the one in the locally running shell script. Setting one will have no effect on the the other. You need to print out the result in the remote script and the local script can read and interpret the output to set the value locally. (Note you can print out your debugging statements to stderr so that they won't interfere with the result printed out to stdout.)

Answer (score 1):

As written in pcarter's comment, the variables on both systems are independent from each other and don't get passed via `ssh`. Instead of setting a variable  (or printing and reading the value as proposed in the comment, which is a working solution) you can use the exit code which gets passed automatically by `ssh`.

The following script is close to the original. For further improvements see below.

```
# !/bin/bash

declare -a server_PP=('XXXXX' 'YYYYYYY' );
declare -A results_map;


function process(){
serverList=$1[@];
servers=("${!serverList}");
status='Failure';
for  serverName in "${servers[@]}"
do
    if ssh  $serverName  <<  EOF
        if [ -f /app/Release/abc.war ]; then
            echo "available - success"
            exit 0;
        fi
        echo "error"
        exit 1
EOF
    then
        status='Success'
    else
        status='Failure'
    fi
echo "***********status-outside******$status"
results_map+=([$serverName]=$status);
done
}


process 'server_PP'

for i in "${!results_map[@]}"
do
  echo "key :" $i
  echo "value:" ${results_map[$i]}
done
```

As you no longer need the variable assignments you can even omit the `if ...` and `exit` in the remote commands.

```
    if ssh  $serverName  <<  EOF
        [ -f /app/Release/abc.war ]
EOF
    then
...
```

Your approach of using a heredoc as

```
ssh hostname <<EOF 
# commands ...
EOF
```

has the disadvantage that you run an interactive shell on the remote system, which may print some system information or welcome message before executing your commands. You can further simplify the script (and removing the welcome message) by specifying the command or a script as command line arguments for `ssh`.

```
    if ssh  $serverName  [ -f /app/Release/abc.war ]
    then
...
```

If your command sequence is longer you can create a script on the remote system and run this script in the same way as `ssh hostname scriptname`. You could also create the script on the remote system using `ssh` or `scp`.

Comment: Using the exit code is a much simpler method that what I suggested. Thanks.